# Relationship between logistic regression and hyperplane

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I have always been a bit confused about logistic regression modeling. If I speak to a statistician, they refer to the modeling efforts in terms of the logit link function. However, if I speak with a machine learning expert, they refer to logistic regression as simply implementing a hyperplane (similar to SVM). What is the relationship between the logistic function and the separating hyperplane?

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The picture below will probably answer your question.

A logistic regression model with 2 features creates a wave based on the logit link function.

[image]

Applying the decision rule (for example above 50%) transforms the wave to a separating hyperplane like that, but not similar to, one found in SVM. This is illustrated in the picture below. Note that this separating hyperplane is in feature space.

[image]

These pictures come from http://blog.data-miners.com/2014/03/lines-and-circles-and-logistic.html You can find an expose on om the subject.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question specifically asks about the *separating* hyperplane. This plane is just the prediction function.

Comment: @user777 Was adding that, and I think done.

Comment: Imposing a decision rule on the prediction equation does not achieve the SVM separating hyperplane. The SVM separating hyperplane exists in the feature space of the kernel function; there is not necessarily anything planar about the separation in the space of the original predictors. This is what people mean when they say the SVM is a nonlinear classifier.

Comment: @user77 I agree and I know, and I don't think that that is the question. I'm stating the fact that the logit function gives rise to a separating hyperplane, not similar to one in SVM, but related to. This is how the two terms can be related to each other.