# Why the Y in logistic regression must be truly binary, not be contrived from an underlying ordinal or continuous response variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I wonder what would happen when the assumption as mentioned in 
[Frank Harrell's answer for "When is logistic regression suitable?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/198093) is violated?

> The primary assumption of logistic regression is that Y is truly binary, e.g. it was not contrived from an underlying ordinal or continuous response variable. It, like classification methods, is for truly all-or-nothing phenomena.

for instance, what would happen if I turn the dependent variable of blood pressure (continuous) into binary (hypertension or not)?

Comment: Idea...run a simulation where you can get good accuracy in predicting a continuous variable (out of sample). Then separate your response variable into two classes and run logistic regression. I’d be very curious how it goes, particularly regarding cases close to the border. (For instance, does the model have much predictive power for those cases compared to random guessing.)

Comment: I suspect the validity of the quotation rests on the intended meaning of "contrived."  In the sense of "you have or can obtain measurements of some underlying continuous variable but have elected to characterize it relative to a threshold," the quotation can be defended as meaning logistic regresssion is an inadmissible procedure.  But under a broader interpretation of "there exists (perhaps unknown or unavailable to you) such an underlying response variable," the assertion is untenable: logistic regression makes *no* such assumptions about the mechanism that might underlie the response.