# is logistic regression only for binary classification?

Tags: logistic, classification, multinomial-logit

Is logistic regression only for binary classification or can it be applied for multi class classifications as well.

Also, can you please list down what are other classification methods for multi classes(for more than 2 classes)

Comment: Logistic regression is *not* a classifier, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044

Answer (score 0):

[Multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) can be used to do multi class classification.

In addition, we can always use "one vs. rest" to turn binary classification to multi class classification (wikipedia [Multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) Transformation to Binary section.

Comment: Thanks hxd1011, could you please kindly elaborate little bit more in it?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster a good place to start would be to review questions bearing the [tag:multinomial-logit] tag.