# Bayes optimal decision for logistic regression: Self-study exercise

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, logistic, bayesian

We want to find the Bayes optimal decision for logistic regression. That means that the goal is to find the actions, which minimize our expected loss (also often called expected cost or risk). Here are the the characteristics:

- $ \begin{equation}
     \text{Conditional distribution $P(y|x)$}  = 
      \begin{cases}
        \sigma (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}), & \text{if}\ y=1 \\
        1-\sigma (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}), & \text{if y= -1}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}$
- Action set = $\{-1,1,D\}$
- $ \begin{equation}
     \text{Cost-function $C(y,a)$} = 
      \begin{cases}
       (\mathbf{1}_{y \neq a}), & \text{if a $\in$ {1,-1}}\  \\
       c < 0.5, & \text{if a = D}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}$

Where $\sigma$ is the Sigmoid-function used in the context of logistic regression. D means that "we don't know". The cost function is written down as follows in our solutions:

$(*) \mathbb{E}[C(a,y)|x] = \int C(y,a)P(y|x)dy = \sum_y (\mathbb{1}[y \neq a]\mathbb{1}[a \neq D]+c*\mathbb{1}[D=a])P(y|x)$

My **question**

The way (*) is written, it reads to me as:

$ (\mathbb{1}[y_1 \neq a]\mathbb{1}[a \neq D]P(y|x)+c*\mathbb{1}[D=a]P(y|x) +
(\mathbb{1}[y_{-1} \neq a]\mathbb{1}[a \neq D]P(y|x)+c*\mathbb{1}[D=a]P(y|x)$

So we are summing up the cost for D twice - is this not wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this is the posterior distribution? It seems the posterior would more look like $p(w|y,x)$

Comment: I am sure, here the source https://las.inf.ethz.ch/courses/lis-s17/hw/hw5_sol.pdf

Comment: Where does it say that? It says conditional distribution as far as I can see

Comment: You are right, I corrected it...I use(d) to think about P(y|x) as the posterior class probability - what would be the difference?

Comment: It's quite different. What is called the conditional distribution here is a model assumption which will lead to the posterior distribution.

Comment: So it's like an estimator of the posterior (intuitively)?

Comment: No it's a model assumption. You assume the data are conditionally Binomial with $y|x \sim Bin(n, \sigma(w^Tx))$, I suppose.

Comment: Hm, why then is it said that "with logistic regression, we estimate directly the *posterior*"  (in comparison to e.g. generative models)?

Comment: This seems to be a strange statement. The posterior is $p(w|y,x)$ and its not estimated but simulated from or approximated

Comment: See e.g. here (section log regression, but also seen often in stats books): https://books.google.ch/books?id=ysucBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA644&lpg=PA644&dq=logistic+regression+estimating+directly+the+posterior&source=bl&ots=BzqlZjXEWx&sig=QvQ39EllmOXIyjZgU7pQO8XqodA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitmPr84L3VAhWBalAKHZ8ZA4IQ6AEIWTAH#v=onepage&q=logistic%20regression%20estimating%20directly%20the%20posterior&f=false

Comment: Ah I think I have seen this before. However, imho the posterior probability is defined as the probability of the parameters given the data. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability

Comment: just fyi you can write $1-\sigma(w^Tx)=\sigma(-w^Tx)$. This means the conditional can be written as $P(y|x)=\sigma(yw^Tx)$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is likely to be less confusing if you first write out the posterior expected loss for each action separately, rather than as one complicated function. It is actually quite simple.

$$E[C(+1,y)|x]=P(y=-1|x)$$
$$E[C(-1,y)|x]=P(y=+1|x)$$
$$E[C(D,y)|x]=c$$

The expected cost for "don't know" doesn't depend on the posterior probabilities, because the cost doesn't depend on $y$. This is why you see it appear "twice" (once for each outcome).

Answer (score 0):

the summation is over $y$ ; in your case $-1$ and $1$. The $P(y|x)$ term will be once for $y=-1$ and once for $y=1$

\begin{align}&(\mathbb1[y_1\ne a]\mathbb1[a\ne D]P(y_1|x)+c\cdot \mathbb1[D=a]P(y_1|x)\\&+(\mathbb1[y_{−1}\ne a]\mathbb1[a\ne D]P(y_{-1}|x)+c\cdot 1[D=a]P(y_{-1}|x)\end{align}