# Minority class misclassification penalty in logistic regression (sklearn)

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, scikit-learn, unbalanced-classes

I am facing the problem of class imbalance in my dataset. Due to some constraints, I cannot use any other classifier than logistic regression in sklearn.

Given that, Can I impose a penalty for misclassification of the minority class to improve the model?

Comment: Logistic regression does not hard classify data points, it estimates probabilities. You can impose misclassification costs when you choose a theeshold on the probabilities.

Comment: Let's say I have a threshold of 0.5. How do I go after this using sklearn?

Comment: No, you CHOOSE the threshold based on the misclassification costs.  You need to write down a matrix of the various misclassification costs, then draw a curve of the expected cost at various thresholds.  You can then choose the optimal threshold.  Sklearn provides a `predict` method that arbitrarily thresholds at 0.5, and you should never use it.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification