# How to modify Presicion and recall of GLM (Logit) in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, unbalanced-classes, threshold

I fit a logistic regression model with an unbalanced population in R.

The problem that I am getting is I have 0.4 for precision and 0.0018 for recall, so I want to modify the threshold in order to get close both indicators (precision and recall)

Do you have any function in R to modify the cutoff? I have seen some work arounds in Python, but the code that I need is in R.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: The [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/predict.glm) suggest that predictions give probabilities.  As such, this question actually has nothing to do with `glm`.  I think you may want to ask a question "How do I round a value in [0,1] according to a given cut-off value $x \in [0,1]$ so that anything less than $x$ returns 0 and anything greater than $x$ returns 1?"  If you need to do that in `R`, it probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, my question is that   "How do I round a value in [0,1] according to a given cut-off value x∈[0,1] so that anything less than x returns 0 and anything greater than x returns 1"?  I really need that!, THanks

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use thresholds at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352)

Don't use precision and recall. [Every criticism that applies to accuracy applies equally to precision and recall.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

[Unbalanced datasets are not a problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352) if you use appropriate quality measures (i.e., not accuracy, precision or recall).

If you still feel you need to work with thresholds, simply use predicted probabilities with `predict(..., type="response")` (see `?predict.glm`) and compare them with your threshold.

Comment: "if you use appropriate quality measures" Would you suggest anything in particular?  Although analysis via a single cut off point may be quite narrow, the set of confusion matrices at every cut off contains a lot of information about the performance of a classifier.  For binary classification problems, accuracy, precision and recall are essentially the confusion matrix.

Comment: @Scott: proper scoring rules are the tool of choice, see the first two links. Per both links, I do not believe confusion matrices are useful. They are improper and misleading, and their very simplicity makes them doubly dangerous.

Comment: Neither of those links seem to suggest anything.  They merely repeat your claim that confusion matrices are not useful.

Comment: Indeed, the answer to this question "What are the consequences of deciding to treat a new observation as class 1 vs. 0? Do I then send out a cheap marketing mail to all 1s? Or do I apply an invasive cancer treatment with big side effects?" goes hand-in-hand with the contents of the confusion matrix since it tells you how many people without cancer are getting your invasive cancer treatment.

Comment: Do you have some example code of:

"If you still feel you need to work with thresholds, simply use predicted probabilities with predict(..., type="response") (see ?predict.glm) and compare them to your threshold"

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @Scott: have you looked at [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352) at the second thread I linked? There are multiple paragraphs on scoring rules as alternatives to accuracy, and as I write, the exact same criticisms that apply to accuracy apply equally to precision and recall, and therefore also to the confusion matrix. Also, [the first link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312124/1352) explicitly addresses that very often we will not have *two* possible actions (treating a case as "positive" vs. "negative"), but more (collect more data if we are unsure).

Comment: @josecorti: `predict.glm(..., type="response")` will give you probabilistic predictions, i.e., numbers between zero and one. You can compare them to a `threshold` value using straightforward comparison operators like `<` and work with index vectors in R. If you have questions about this, then it might be best to ask a separate question [at StackOverflow in the R tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), since that is not about statistics any more. Feel free to link to that new question here, then I'll try to take a look.

Comment: @Scott: on the shortcomings of the confusion matrix, [here is another example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/405049/1352). Yes, I do write about this often, I'll admit it's a bugbear of mine.

Comment: Many of your criticisms are fair.  However, I think that it is often necessary to use the confusion matrix precisely because of the reasons that your answers say not to.  Very frequently, we make a decision based on the outcome of a classifier, and the intermediate probability calculation is irrelevant to how the model ends up being used.  Arguably, people should take the pseudo-probabilistic output into account somehow, but ML systems being what they are these days, that rarely happens: the machine makes a decision totally independently of any human input.

Comment: It's also worth noting that many of the criticisms of accuracy are of using accuracy *only*.  The same apply to using recall and precision *only*, but go away when one considers the entire confusion matrix.  Not all criticisms, but one can never address every possible criticism of anything, I suppose.