# the weights in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

As I am studying Logistic regression, I just wanted to confirm that I understand it correctly,
my main concern is the equation wx+b.

here is my understanding :

(logistic regression is an algorithm used to classify things. The goal is to classify.
So let’s assume that we are classifying if something belongs to class 0 or class 1 .
We use a function that gives us a probability  of it belonging to a class 0 or 1.
We set a threshold such as 0.5, if the prob above 0.5 it belongs to class 1 and vice versa.
The function that gives us values between 0 and 1 is called sigmoid.
the logistic regression uses decision boundary to decide to which class the data belong to, this decision boundary has the weights w and has the formula of : wx + b or w1x1+w2x2+ b )

or are the weights for the sigmoid and not for the decision boundary ?

Comment: think of it like this. wx + b is linear regression. you fit a curve to your data, it will give you a continuous value. when you want to do binary classification, you want a probability distribution. so sigmoid(wx + b) gives you the probability of the positive class. it squeezes the continuous linear output to [0,1]. so the decision boundary would typically be a linear line dividing the sigmoid(wx+b) curve in half. the relationship of w and the logistic curve is not linear.

Comment: Several points in your understanding are not quite correct, starting with "logistic regression is an algorithm used to classify things". It might be interesting to read about [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification).